# Is there an Install Updates, Restart, Finish Installing Updates, and then Shutdown?

Tags: windows, windows-update

I get that there's an "Install Updates and Shutdown" option, but it only installs them halfway. Then, when I'm ready to use the computer again and turn it back on I have to wait for the updates to finish installing. Which apparently takes anywhere from 30 minutes to a few hours.

Obviously when I tell it to install updates on shutdown it's because I don't want to wait on it when I'm actually planning on using the computer.

Is there a way to tell it to "Install Updates, Restart, Finish Installing Updates, and then Shutdown"?

Comment: Chnage your user habits, instead of shutting down, restart the computer.  Use scheduled tasks to shutdown your computer at certain times.  Why is this tagged Windows 7 and Windows 10, you should, clarify your question

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately there is no group policy or command line command that can do this command.

If your concern is that the computer is running and consuming power, you can use the power settings to hibernate after a certain time in minutes. However, if you only want the computer to hibernate one time for the update, you'll have to manually turn off the automatic hibernate again. To do this:

1. Access power settings. You can do this by pressing `win + r` then typing either `powercfg.cpl` or `control.exe /name Microsoft.PowerOptions`. *If you have a laptop, then you can just right click the battery icon and click on power options.*
2. Then `Change Plan Settings` > `Change advanced power settings` then maxmize the `Sleep` list item, then the nested `Hibernate` list item. Modify the time in minutes before hibernation.

---

If you feel a little fancier, you can also schedule a one time task:

1. Press `win + r` then type `Taskschd.msc`.
2. Create task
3. Add a new trigger `at startup`
4. Add a new action program/script: `shutdown.exe` with arguments `-s -f -t 60`
5. Go to settings tab, check the "If the task is not scheduled to run again, delete it after:" and set the combo-box to `Immediately` so the task goes away after it finishes.

**Note**: I set the force shutdown time window to be one minute. This is just in case something goes wrong, if it were set to 0 your computer has the potential of shutting down as soon as you startup computer, which would be a problem in of itself. If this does happen for some reason, login quickly, open a cmd or powershell and type in `shutdown.exe /a` which will abort any pending shutdown command.

---

An additional note on hibernating/sleep: only one or the other can be active at one time. You've probably noticed, but you have only the sleep option or the hibernate option when you click the power button in start menu. If you currently have the sleep option on and you want hibernate, open **an elevated** powershell or cmd (press `win + x` or `right click start button`) and then type `powercfg /h on` to turn on hibernation, and `powercfg /h off` to turn on sleep/hybrid mode.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is no. Windows updates and installation has to follow a procedure install to minimize risk of ruining your computer. Some installations require a restart to complete, so if you shut down, it will resume the next time you turn on the computer.